# Get the Most frequent element in an array

Tags: javascript, comparative-review, mathematics

I have been trying to optimize this:

```js
const NUMBERS = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9];

const getMode = (arr) => arr
    .sort(
      (a, b) =>
        arr.reduce((acu, cur) => (cur === a ? (acu += 1) : cur)) -
        arr.reduce((acu, cur) => (cur === b ? (acu += 1) : cur))
    )
    .pop();

console.log(getMode(NUMBERS));
```

I had thought about this too:

```js
const NUMBERS = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9];

const mode = (arr) => arr
    .sort(
      (a, b) =>
        arr.filter((v) => v === a).length - arr.filter((v) => v === b).length
    )
    .pop();
    
console.log(mode(NUMBERS))
```

What do you think can be improved?

Comment: To clarify, what do you mean by “mode”? The statistical zero-th moment of a distribution?

Comment: The element that is repeated the most in the array

Comment: You've said "trying to optimize". Did you profile the code? What did you get? Anyway, it should be clear that sorting to get the maximum is a bad idea.

Comment: Do you want to improve speed or memory usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to improve the performance, you can reduce the complexity of the code.

Currently, the complexity of your approaches is **O(n² log(n))** as the `sort` function is **O(n log(n))** and in each iteration, you are using `filter` or `reduce` which has a complexity of **O(n)**.

I can suggest one approach where you don't need to sort the elements and so the complexity of the method will be **O(n)** if using [V8](https://v8.dev/) JavaScript Engine ([for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611509/es6-map-and-set-complexity-v8-implementation)) otherwise **O(n log(n))**. Check out this approach:

```js
const NUMBERS = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9];

const getMode = (arr) => {

  let [maxFreq, result] = [-1, -1];
        
  arr.reduce((acu, cur) => {
                  acu.set(cur, (acu.has(cur) ? acu.get(cur) : 0)+1)
                  return acu;
                 }, new Map())
            .forEach((value, key) => {
                if(value > maxFreq){
                  maxFreq = value;
                  result = key;
                }
              });
  
  return result;
    
 }

console.log(getMode(NUMBERS))
```

Comment: Yeah... @PavloSlavynskyy... thanks for correcting!

Comment: @PavloSlavynskyy according to this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611509/es6-map-and-set-complexity-v8-implementation) discussion in V8 JavaScript Engine the time complexity of retrieval and lookup is O(1)

Answer (score 1):

### Sort!

Never use a sort to get a max or min. Sort is only used to order all items in the array.

If you want a max in an array you can use `Math.max(...[1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2])` expresses 6.

If you need an associated value linked to a max or min you will need to iterate manually storing the max and associated data as and when you find new values.

### Rewrite

The example tests the count of values against a max `max` and store both the max count and the value `maxVal` of the counted value

To count values it uses a map which uses a hash map and is \$O(1)\$ for lookups which will make the function \$O(n)\$

```js
function getMode(data) {
    var max = -Infinity, maxVal, counts = new Map(), c;
    for (const v of data) {
        c = ++(counts.get(v) ?? (counts.set(v, c = {count: 0}), c)).count;
        [max, maxVal] = c > max ? [c, v] : [max, maxVal];
    }
    return maxVal;
}

console.log(getMode([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9]))
```

You could also check if max is greater than (n / 2) and exit as if the count is over half the items the value must be the most frequent.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the answer of the HandsomeCoder.

This is actually O(n) because object access is O(1)

```js
const NUMBERS = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9];

function getMode(array) {
    function buildFrequencyMap(array) {
        return array.reduce((acu, number) => {
            acu[number] = acu[number] !== undefined ? acu[number] + 1 : 0
            return acu;
        }, {})
    }

    function maxFrequency(frequencyMap) {
        let maxFreq = -1, result = -1

        Object.entries(frequencyMap).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            if(value > maxFreq){
                maxFreq = value;
                result = key;
            }
        });

        return result
    }

    const frequencyMap = buildFrequencyMap(array)

    return maxFrequency(frequencyMap);
}

console.log(getMode(NUMBERS))
```